# Rails Many - Many Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have three tables associated and am trying to do a simple search.

```
User Table
ID | Name

User_Contacts Table
User_ID | Contact_ID | Updated_At

Contacts Table
ID | Name
```

I currently have my associations set up such that I can do the following

```
@contacts = @current_user.contacts
```

and have the User_Contacts table returned. I would like to keep it this way because I still need my updated_at attribute in my view.

Now what I need to do is some how search through the contacts table and find every contact where there name is like "%mike%" and have this update my @contacts variable. Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way but I'm clueless where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `@current_user.contacts.where("name LIKE ?", "%Mike%")` work?

Comment: no because the column name doesn't exist in the User_Contacts table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike,

Here's a sample app that does what you're looking for. Check out the Readme.markdown for sample usage.

https://github.com/JumpstartLab/contacts

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
@contacts = Contact.includes(:user_contacts).where("name like ? and user_contacts.id = ?", "%mike%", @current_user.id)
```

The magic bit there is the `.includes`, which eager-loads associated tables. There are a lot of technical implications to consider, but you can read up more on those here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html